# Excel - Append cell2 to cell1 if cell3 is not blank

Tags: excel, cell, formula, equation

All,

I've taken a browse around and I've been unable to nail down the formula I'm looking for. I'm a bit new to Excel expressions, so this is all part of the learning process.

*My quandary*:

I have a list of names in an Excel spreadsheet - some have two components and some have three. I need all names to have only two components - if they have three, then the first two components need to be combined.

*Here is my workflow*:

IF cell 3 is occupied, append the content of cell 2 to the end of cell 1 IN cell 1. Then, assuming cell 2 is now blank, move the content of cell 3 to cell 2. Else, do nothing.

So my input might be (assuming each group of characters is in its own cell):

- JOHN SMITH
- JOHN DOE SMITH
- BARRY JOHNSON
- RICHARD P RICKSON
- JACK JACK GILES

My output would be:

- JOHN SMITH
- JOHNDOE SMITH
- BARRY JOHNSON
- RICHARDP RICKSON
- JACKJACK GILES

What's your take on this?

Comment: Are "John" "Doe" and "Smith" in three different cells?

Comment: Yep, that's how that would be input initially. Only in the ideal end output would John and Doe be in cell 1, and Smith in cell 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in columns A, B, and C, this will put the correct output in columns D and E.

In column D:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),A1,CONCAT(A1,B1))
```

In column E:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),B1,C1)
```